# CSS3 adjust height in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this jsfiddle here and it work fine as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/fdjQs/1/

Then I've tried to adjust the **height** size as below:

```
 #wrapper {width:320px;height:480px;background-color:#eee}
 #pageWrapper {width:320px;height:440px;overflow:hidden;position:relative}
 #pages {width:320px;height:1320px;background-color:#fed;position:absolute}
 #nav {width:320px;height:40px}
 div.pageDiv {width:320px;height:440px}
 #page2 {background-color:#666666}
 #page3 {background-color:#999999}
 #pagesNav {display:none}
```

It goes funny and it doesn't look like what is should look of a working result (BUT, with a corrected height size as above) http://jsfiddle.net/fdjQs/1/

UPDATE:

**Overall size 320px width x 480px height**

**nav (top) 320px width x 40px height**

**content 320px x 440px height**

Can anyone enlighten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onclick handler `onclick="movePage(250,2);"` for each link in the HTML passes a `y` value which needs to be modified, too.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="movePage(440,2);">Page 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="movePage(880,2);">Page 3</a>
```

Comment: Thank you shhac. I've accepted your answer. It worked as as Laurence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `movePage` calls too:

```
<div class="pageDiv" id="page1">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="movePage(440,2);">Page 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="movePage(880,2);">Page 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Laurence. I've accepted your answer. It worked. But could not use both green tick.

Comment: That's fine, @shhac answered first anyway :)